# In-line code block

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments

If you still don't know this, you can create an inline version of the code block, by using backticks (`), it's a great thing if you want to post golf ideas in the comments, but this is also one of it's flaw.

Javascript is a pretty popular golfing language on this site, multiple people use it (for example Neil or Conor O' Brien). There's a feature in javascript ES6, wich allows you to leave out parentheses on the functions, wich take in a string as a parameter by doing:

```
functionName`String comes here`
```

The back tick also allows you, to use literal new lines, instead of \n-s.

The problem with this though, that whenever we want to post a new better golfed code in the comments, the back ticks of the program interfere with the in-line code blocks, creating something like this:

`Array(100).fill`abc`.join`|``

(This is a worst case example)

I don't want to change the markup for the in-line code-block, I only want to have an alternative for it.

Comment: You can also use 2 backticks, `\`\`foo\`\``, around the code.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ That doesn't work in comments.

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ ``join˙˙.split`|```

Comment: @Doorknob except for ``\`` for some weird reason...

Comment: Ooops.. Just read the comments. Let's check: ``` Array(100).fill`abc`.join`` ``` Really, not working :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment markdown allows you to escape backticks in inline code. So,

```
`Array(100).fill\`abc\`.join\`|\``
```

results in

`` Array(100).fill`abc`.join`|` ``

Answer (score 0):

Markdown allows multiple `` ` `` to be used for inline code. It also trims spaces at the end. So

````
``` Array(100).fill`abc`.join`` ```
````

becomes ``` Array(100).fill`abc`.join`` ```.

Comment: Not in comments (which is what the question is asking), except for the special case of `\`\`\\`\``

Comment: @MartinEnder, yep.. It's sad...

Comment: Is it really a special case? ``.`.``

Comment: It seems to me `\`` cannot be the first or last character in `\`\` \`\``.

Comment: Let's check: ``-`` `\`` ```...``...```. @jimmy23013, seems like trimming doesn't work in comments, so if you code starts from or ends by `\`` you have to use escaping, otherwise you can yse multiple `\``.

Comment: ``Yet `` another `` test``. `` 1 `` 2 ``3      4`` 5 ``6` `` 7 ``Array(100).fill`abc`.join`|` ``

Comment: A trailing space seemed working, but not a leading one.